# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in assembly x86-64

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault

I wrote a code in assembly and I'm getting a segmentation fault. Would greatly appreciate help in finding the bug. Except for the stack usage for my function calls, I only have one variable in the memory (input) so I don't really understand why there would be a segmentation fault... here is my code (it's a calculator):

```
.global _start

.section .bss
.lcomm input, 1

.section .text
.global calc_expr

calc_expr:
xor %rcx, %rcx
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp

readchar: #reading character one by one from stdin
movq $0, %rax
movq $0, %rdi
movq input, %rsi
movq $1, %rdx
syscall

#character = (
cmp $40, (input)
jne no_new_parenthesis
call calc_expr
jmp readchar

no_new_parenthesis:
#character = new line
cmp $10, (input)
je end      

#character = )
cmp $41, (input)
je epilogue

#character = +
cmp $43, (input)
je plus

#character = -
cmp $45, (input)
je minus

#character = *
cmp $42, (input)
je multiply

#character = /
cmp $47, (input)
je divide

#character = number
pushq %rcx
movq (input), %rdi
call string_convert #convert string to number, from rdi into rax
popq %rcx
imul $10, %rcx, %rcx
add %rax, %rcx
jmp readchar

plus:
pushq %rcx
call calc_expr
popq %r8
addq %r8, %rcx
jmp readchar

minus: 
pushq %rcx
call calc_expr
popq %r8
subq %rcx, %r8
mov %r8, %rcx
jmp readchar

multiply:
pushq %rcx
call calc_expr
popq %r8
imul %r8, %rcx
jmp readchar

divide:
pushq %rcx
call calc_expr
popq %rax
xor %rdx, %rdx
idiv %rcx
mov %rax, %rcx
jmp readchar

end:
#convert number to string, from rdi into what_to_print, rax = length of string
movq %rcx, %rdi
call result_as_string

#printing result
movq %rax, %rdx
movq $1, %rax
movq $1, %rdi
movq what_to_print, %rsi
syscall

epilogue:
leave
ret
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a debugger to find which instruction is the faulting one.

Comment: Also, what is the faulting input? What in `_start`, do you have a proper ending there? What is in the missing functions? Note that `movq (input), %rdi` is loading 64 bits (8 bytes) instead of 1 that you probably want.

Comment: Similarly all your `cmp` instructions silently default to accessing 4 bytes, you probably want `cmpb`. `movq input, %rsi` is missing a `$` because you want to pass the address there. Probably the same thing for `what_to_print`.

Comment: Thank you! This was really really helpful! question: do i not need to wirte .global _start in the beginning? can i just write the section .bss and section .text part?

Comment: You don't need that if you don't define your own `_start`. Is something else calling your function?

Comment: Thank you, no nothing else is calling my function but there is recursion in there so it's calling itself.

Comment: Since you end with a `ret` there is most definitely something else calling your function. E.g. a C driver for example.